# PostgreSQL agentless backup history collection

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

I have a service that is collecting information from PostgreSQL databases using queries. After some searching, it seems like that you cannot collect backup history using SQL.

Is there an alternative way of collecting this information? It needs to be agentless.

Comment: can you add some examples of what you want to achieve and elaborate on this limitation of SQL?

Comment: For example, in MS SQL you can retrieve DB backup history from the `msdb.dbo.backupset` table. But it does not seem like Postgres has anything similar.

Comment: @Marius How are you doing your backups?

Comment: @Bergi We don't create the backups. Our service is a service offering. So irrelevant of how the backups are done, we want to be able to pull the history. But it seems like we'll have to do this through Shell and read the WAL.

Comment: @Marius Then you'll want to ask your service provider how to get the backup history. We can't help you without more details.

Comment: @Bergi, this has nothing to do with the client. This is strictly PostgreSQL. If a backup is made using `pg_basebackup`, how do we see the history of that using a query? From what I've seen, this is not possible. My question is around alternate methods of collecting this information that is agentless.

Comment: "*If a backup is made using `pg_basebackup`*" - thanks, that's the bit you should've mentioned.

Comment: It seems like you could access the [backup history files](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-BASE-BACKUP) using the `pg_ls_archive_statusdir` and `pg_read_file` [generic file access functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE)

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. I'll look into this.